# Transfer Frozen: Free Fall progress between devices

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-2, data-transfer, samsung-galaxy-s-5

How can I transfer my progress in [Frozen: Free Fall](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.disney.frozensaga_goo) from my Samsung Galaxy S2 (Android 2.3.3) to my Samsung Galaxy S5?

Comment: In SD card android->data folder copy the folder name of the game and paste it in the new device

Comment: @sameer Don't forget that comments are for clarifying the question, not for answering the question.

Answer (score 3):

In SD card `android->data` folder copy the folder name of the game and paste it in the new device